# how to get the text in one of the divs? (html)

Tags: python

I am writing my bot, which so far has to get the text from the div from one page and put it in a variable, but this does not work out and the variable always remains empty. How i can extract it?

```
import telebot;
import requests
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html
import csv
bot = telebot.TeleBot('');

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    api = requests.get("https://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=21880")
    tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(api.text)
    text_original = tree.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/index/div[2]/p[1]/strong/text()')
    print(text_original)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,str(text_original))
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

https://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=21880

I think this code should get the word "ОЛЕКВАС", I copied the path to it and added /text(), but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I have no cyrillic on my system, but with a smaller xpath value and the usage from text_content it print something on shell, hopefully it helps

```
api = requests.get("https://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=21880")
tree = lxml.html.document_fromstring(api.text)
text_original = tree.xpath('//div[@align="justify"]/p/strong')
print(text_original[0].text_content())
```